# Java - Spring Boot - Mysql / Java - Get type of vehicle from a column of a table and get their total count(QUANTITY) from another table

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

This is the scenario I want to do:
There are two tables: the vehicle table with columns: vehicleType, brand. And the shipment table with the columns: desc, vehicleType, date_delivered, date_dispatched.

I want to get all the vehicleType from the vehicle table and get the total count of shipment they have done in the shipment table. But the problem is, I dont know what to do to get that.

> Shipment.java

```
    package com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;


/**
 * Delivery of goods
 * @author JRDomingo
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="shipment")
public class Shipment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Column(name="booking_number",unique=true)
    public String bookingNumber;

    @Column(name="wb_number")
    public String wbNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="vehicle_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Vehicle vehicle;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Customer customer;

    public String origin;

    public String depot;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="vendor_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Vendor vendor;

    public String type;

    @Column(name="commodity_type")
    public String commodityType;

    @Column(name="truck_type")
    public String truckType;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Status status;

    @Column(name="delivery_date")
    public Date deliveryDate;

    @Column(name="fuel_po")
    public String fuelPo;

    @Column(name="client_ref_no")
    public String clientReferenceNumber;

    public String remarks;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="driver_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public Personnel driver;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="helper1_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public Personnel helper1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="helper2_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public Personnel helper2;


    public enum Status{
        New, Dispatched, Delivered, Completed, Cancelled
    }

    /******
     * ACTUAL DATES IMPLEMENTED
     ******/
    @Column(name="date_created")
    public Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name="date_dispatched")
    public Date dateDispatched;

    @Column(name="date_completed")
    public Date dateCompleted;

    @Column(name="date_cancelled")
    public Date dateCancelled;

    @Column(name="date_received")
    public Date dateReceived;

    @Column(name="farthest_destination")
    public String farthestDestination;

    @Column(name="client_rate")
    public Double clientRate;

    @Column(name="is_sub_con")
    public boolean isSubCon;

    @Column(name="sub_con_rate")
    public Double subConRate;

    @Column(name="fuel")
    public Double fuel;

    @Column(name="fuel_amount")
    public Double fuelAmount;

    @Column(name="route_code")
    public String routeCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="dispatched_odometer_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public RegularOdometerUsage dispatchedOdometer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="delivered_odometer_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public RegularOdometerUsage deliveredOdometer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="completed_odometer_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public RegularOdometerUsage completedOdometer;


    /**
     * index 0 = Driver , index 1 = Helper1, index 2 = Helper2
     */
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="shipment",targetEntity=PersonnelRate.class)
    public List<PersonnelRate> personnelRates = new ArrayList<PersonnelRate>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Company company;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="prepared_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public User preparedBy;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_invoice", referencedColumnName="id")
    public CustomerInvoice customerInvoice;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="trucker_settlement", referencedColumnName="id")
    public TruckerSettlement truckerSettlement;

}
```

Comment: Do u have any mapping between those two tables

Comment: I am just using the spring JPA repository.

Comment: share your entity details

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNT() with the GROUP BY to group them together by vehicleType

```
SELECT
 vehicle.vehicleType,
 count(shipment.id) as totalShipment
FROM
 Vehicle as vehicle
INNER JOIN Shipment as shipment ON shipment.vehicleType = vehicle.vehicleType group by vehicle.vehicleType
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir, but what i mean is like this vehilcle table: vehicletype = TRUCK, VAN, CAR, TRAILER.  shipment table: vehicletype=VAN, desc=deliver Items
vehicletype=TRUCK, desc=movers rent
vehicletype=VAN, desc=camping trip
vahicletype=TRUCK, desc=deliver items

Comment: @cleem can you share entity mapping so i can get better idea ?

Comment: @cleem using this query in your JPA repository you will get vehicleType with number of totalShiment done for this vehicleType.